# Find user is registered to a Event in MongoDb (aggregation)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I tried to find users who are registered for that event.

So I **join** multiple collections shown below -

```
Events.aggregate([
            { $match: { category: "group_event" } },


            // collection where events are scheduled
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "group_events",
                    let: { eventId: "$eventID" },
                    pipeline: [
                        {
                            $match: {
                                $expr: {
                                    $and: [
                                        { $eq: ["$_id", "$$eventId"] },

                                        { $gt: ["$time", new Date()] },
                                    ],
                                },
                            },
                        },

                         // register user collection
                        {
                            $lookup: {
                                from: "register_events",
                                let: { eventId: "$_id" },
                                pipeline: [
                                    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$eventId", "$$eventId"] } } },
                                ],
                                as: "registerUsers",
                            },
                        },

                    ],
                    as: "events",
                },
            },
            { $unwind: "$events" },
            
        ])
```

and the **output** is now comingout -

```
[
        {
            "_id": "614d6dfd82cb36be231083c9",
            "trainerId": "61488dc36b7ccedbc884d20a",
            "category": "group_event",
            "eventID": "614d6dfc82cb36be231083c7",
            "createdAt": "2021-09-24T06:19:41.268Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-09-24T06:19:41.268Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "events": {
                "_id": "614d6dfc82cb36be231083c7",
                "groupName": "group name 4",
                "category": "sdfsdf",
                "time": "2021-09-27T07:44:58.762Z",
                "description": "description",
                "day": "sunday",
                "platform": "zoom",
                "notes": "22",
                "skills_to_learn": [
                    "demo"
                ],
                "status": "pending",
                "trainerId": "61488dc36b7ccedbc884d20a",
                "meetingLink": "https://us05web.zoom.us/j/81660534858?pwd=cGZaODVjdWJUQWNtN243MlNiVUN0UT09",
                "type": "group_event",
                 **isUserRegisted : true / false,**
                "createdAt": "2021-09-24T06:19:41.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-09-24T06:19:41.000Z",
                "__v": 0,
                "registerUsers": [
                    {
                        "_id": "614ed6b4b8a545acb8517e85",
                        "userId": "614d59371d11becb8e23f536",
                        "eventId": "614d6dfc82cb36be231083c7",
                        "question": "",
                        "createdAt": "2021-09-25T07:58:44.939Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2021-09-25T07:58:44.939Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
```

which is ok for me bu just wanted to add a **key: value**, heighlited on obove section

```
isUserRegisted : true / false
```

i tried with **$addFields** but can't came up with any solution. Basically I need to retrieve arrays from **registerUsers**  - collection and on the same time match the **userId**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out this issue.

simply I need to use **$project** and **$filter** to get the data if available and at last use $cond to **return true or false**

```
{
    $project: {
        root: "$$ROOT",
        userFound: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$registerUsers",
                as: "ac",
                cond: {
                    $eq: ["$$ac.userId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)],
                },
            },
        },
    },
},

{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        document: "$$ROOT",
        userFound: {
            $cond: {
                if: { $isArray: "$userFound" },
                then: {
                    $cond: {
                        if: {
                            $gt: [{ $size: "$userFound" }, 0],
                        },
                        then: true,
                        else: false,
                    },
                },
                else: false,
            },
        },
    },
},

// merging nested object with parents
{
    $replaceRoot: {
        newRoot: {
            $mergeObjects: [
                "$document.root",
                { isUserRegistered: "$userFound" },
            ],
        },
    },
},
```